# Create VMSS from snapshot

Tags: azure, powershell, virtual-machine

I have a snapshot of VM is it possible to create VMSS with security type as Trusted Launch from snapshot?

I tried creating image from snapshot and deploy VMSS from image. But getting error

```
$rgName = "existing-snapshot-rg"
$location = "EastUS"
$snapshotName = "Myexistingsnapshot"
$imageName = "myImage3"
$vnetName = "my-vnet"
$vmssNetwork = "vmss-network"
$VMSSName = "vmssnapshot"
$computerName = "computer"
$securityType = "TrustedLaunch";

$snapshot = Get-AzSnapshot -ResourceGroupName $rgName -SnapshotName $snapshotName
$imageConfig = New-AzImageConfig -Location $location -HyperVGeneration v2
$imageConfig1 = Set-AzImageOsDisk -Image $imageConfig -OsState Generalized -OsType Windows -SnapshotId $snapshot.Id
New-AzImage -ImageName $imageName -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Image $imageConfig1

#Get the custom image 
$image = Get-AzureRmImage -ResourceGroupName $rgName -ImageName $imageName

# Get the existing Vnet
$vnet = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $vnetName

#IP configuration
$ipName = "ipConfig1"

#create the IP configuration
$ipConfig = New-AzureRmVmssIpConfig -Name $ipName -LoadBalancerBackendAddressPoolsId $null -SubnetId $vnet.Subnets[0].Id

#create vmss configuration
$vmss = New-AzureRmVmssConfig -Location "East US" -SkuCapacity 2 -SkuName "Standard_D2s_v3" -UpgradePolicyMode "Automatic" -ErrorAction Stop
$vmss1 = Set-AzVmssSecurityProfile -VirtualMachineScaleSet $vmss -SecurityType $securityType;

##Add the network interface configuration to the scale set configuration
Add-AzureRmVmssNetworkInterfaceConfiguration -VirtualMachineScaleSet $vmss1 -Name $vmssNetwork -Primary $true -IPConfiguration $ipConfig 

# set the stroage profile 
Set-AzureRmVmssStorageProfile -VirtualMachineScaleSet $vmss1 -OsDiskCreateOption "FromImage" -OsDiskCaching "None" -ImageReferenceId $image.Id -OsDiskOsType Windows

#set the os profile
Set-AzureRmVmssOSProfile -ComputerNamePrefix $computerName -AdminUsername "azureuser" -AdminPassword "azureuser@2018" -VirtualMachineScaleSet $vmss1

#create the vmss
New-AzVMss -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $VMSSName -VirtualMachineScaleSet $vmss1
```

Error :
New-AzVmss: Managed Images are not supported for virtual machines with security type
TrustedLaunch.
ErrorCode: BadRequest
ErrorMessage: Managed Images are not supported for virtual machines with security type TrustedLaunch.
ErrorTarget:
StatusCode: 400
ReasonPhrase: Bad Request

Answer (score 0):

> Error : New-AzVmss: Managed Images are not supported for virtual
> machines with security type TrustedLaunch. ErrorCode: BadRequest
> ErrorMessage: Managed Images are not supported for virtual machines with security type TrustedLaunch. ErrorTarget: StatusCode: 400
> ReasonPhrase: Bad Request

The error usually occurs if Trusted launch is not enabled in snapshot. Check this [MsDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/generation-2#generation-2-vm-sizes) of supported vm generation.

Created a snapshot or generalized the vm and in disk and create snapshot with security type trusted lunch like below.

[image]

If trusted lunch is not enabled in snapshot, you should use `Trusted launch VM Supported` source type. Refer this [MsDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/trusted-launch-portal?tabs=powershell,portal2,portal3#deploy-a-trusted-launch-vm-from-an-azure-compute-gallery-image)

You can make use of below PowerShell script for trusted lunch:

```
$rgName = "MyResourceGroup"
$galleryName = "MyGallery"
$galleryImageDefinitionName = "MyImageDef"
$location = "eastus"
$publisherName = "TrustedlaunchPublisher"
$offerName = "TrustedlaunchOffer"
$skuName = "TrustedlaunchSku"
$description = "My gallery"
$SecurityType = @{Name='SecurityType';Value='TrustedLaunch'}
$features = @($SecurityType)
New-AzGalleryImageDefinition -ResourceGroupName $rgName -GalleryName $galleryName -Name $galleryImageDefinitionName -Location $location -Publisher $publisherName -Offer $offerName -Sku $skuName -HyperVGeneration "V2" -OsState "Generalized" -OsType "Windows" -Description $description -Feature $features
```

Generalize the Trusted launch VM and image version like below:

[image]

[image]

When snapshot is not enabled Trusted lunch, the security type on the image definition should be set to `TrustedLaunchsupported`:

You can make use of below PowerShell script for Trusted Launch supported:

```
$rgName = "MyResourceGroup"
$galleryName = "MyGallery"
$galleryImageDefinitionName = "MyImageDef"
$location = "eastus"
$publisherName = "TrustedlaunchPublisher"
$offerName = "TrustedlaunchOffer"
$skuName = "TrustedlaunchSku"
$description = "My gallery"
$SecurityType = @{Name='SecurityType';Value='TrustedLaunchSupported'}
$features = @($SecurityType)
New-AzGalleryImageDefinition -ResourceGroupName $rgName -GalleryName $galleryName -Name $galleryImageDefinitionName -Location $location -Publisher $publisherName -Offer $offerName -Sku $skuName -HyperVGeneration "V2" -OsState "Generalized" -OsType "Windows" -Description $description -Feature $features
```

Now, I am able to create virtual machine scale set security type as Trusted Launch from snapshot successfully like below:

[image]

[image]

***Reference:***

[Deploy a trusted launch VM - Azure Virtual Machines | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/trusted-launch-portal?tabs=portal%2Cpowershell2%2Cpowershell3)

Comment: how did you create image from snapshot? It look like my image created from snapshot is managed and it's not allowed to create TL VMSS from managed OS.
 the two snippets you have shared to create Image ref is same. It's not using the snapshot you created. 

My snapshot is TL enabled.

Comment: Can you please share what's required to create VMSS using Snapshot with security type Trusted Launch?

Comment: Imran, I checked that but it doesn't share how to create un managed Image using snapshot.

Comment: check this [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/tutorial-use-custom-image-powershell)